# How can I install Visual Studio to a removable media like DVD?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I install Visual Studio to a removable media like DVD? I want to present a Visual Studio project at college but my college doesn't have Visual Studio installed to provide the platform for my project; can I run Visual Studio from a DVD?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem possible, but you have several options to work with.

- If you just want to show off your completed application, then you can compile it and put it on a CD/DVD/flash drive/in the cloud/something else. Be careful, though, that you have all of the prerequisites installed on the school computer. If you're working with VB.NET, C#, or another .NET Framework language, you'll need to make sure the computer at your school has the right version of the .NET Framework on it. You can download the newest version of the framework here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718.
- If you need to actually show the IDE yourself, and can't get a laptop or anything to bring with it on there, you can look into remote desktop. You'd have to set up a remote desktop server on your home computer. Here are some instructions on doing that in Windows 7: http://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-setup-remote-desktop-with-windows-7/ Remember, however, that you'll have to port-forward port 3389 (TCP) at home, and your educational institution may block outgoing requests on that port, so you should look in to how possible that is, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you install Windows XP (due to it's smaller size compared to Vista or 7) and Visual Studio to a virtual machine, and take its disk file along with the virtualization software on a DVD or USB key.